# Stratified random sample in dplyr with filtered groups

Tags: r, dplyr, sampling

I am trying to create a stratified random sample of files based on two grouping variables (a sensor location and a date). Not all sensors have the same number of observations (batteries die on the last day).

The main thing I am working on is using dplyr to process my data, by getting a number of observations for each sensor-day combination and filtering out those that have fewer than I want for my eventual stratified sample.

This is the head of the data I am working with:

```
structure(list(fullPath = c("S4A00440_20180508_123353.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_123353.wav", "S4A00440_20180508_130000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_133000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_140000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_143000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_150000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_153000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_160000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_163000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_170000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_173000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_180000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_183000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_190000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_193000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_200000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_203000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_210000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_213000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_220000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_223000.flac", "S4A00440_20180508_230000.flac", 
"S4A00440_20180508_233000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_130000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_130000.wav", "S4A00466_20180508_133000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_140000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_143000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_150000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_153000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_160000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_163000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_170000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_173000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_180000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_183000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_190000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_193000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_200000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_203000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_210000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_213000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_220000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_223000.flac", 
"S4A00466_20180508_230000.flac", "S4A00466_20180508_233000.flac"), 
sensorName = c("S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", 
"S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", 
"S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", 
"S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00440", 
"S4A00440", "S4A00440", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", 
"S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", 
"S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", 
"S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", "S4A00466", 
"S4A00466"), 
Date = structure(c(1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 
1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 
1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 
1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 
1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 
1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 
1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 
1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 1525737600, 
1525737600, 1525737600), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
row.names = c(1114L, 1115L, 1116L, 1117L, 1118L, 1119L, 1120L, 1121L, 1122L, 1123L, 
1124L, 1125L, 1126L, 1127L, 1128L, 1129L, 1130L, 1131L, 1132L, 
1133L, 1134L, 1135L, 1136L, 1137L, 1395L, 1396L, 1397L, 1398L, 
1399L, 1400L, 1401L, 1402L, 1403L, 1404L, 1405L, 1406L, 1407L, 
1408L, 1409L, 1410L, 1411L, 1412L, 1413L, 1414L, 1415L, 1416L, 
1417L), class = "data.frame")
```

How I tried to do the sampling

```
foo_strat <- foo %>% 
  select(fullPath, sensorName, Date) %>% 
  group_by(sensorName, Date) %>% 
  summarise(num_recs = length(fullPath)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(num_recs > 12) %>% 
  sample_n(12)
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Error: 'size' must be less or equal than 7 (size of data), set `replace` = TRUE to use sampling with replacement

I checked [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1438) which suggests that what I'm trying to do may just not be the behavior of the function, in which case I'm not sure what would be the best way to proceed

Comment: Your dput is not complete.  Please copy/paste the full dput output

Comment: thanks for that. I reformatted and added more data to the dput which should make the error more reproducible.

Comment: Yes, you have only a single row after the `summarise` step for each group

Answer (score 0):

The `summarise` summarises to single row per each group.  So, we don't hae enough data points to do the `sample_n`. Instead, we can directly apply the `filter` on the whole data with `n()` (giving the number of rows)

```
library(dplyr)
foo %>% 
   select(fullPath, sensorName, Date) %>% 
   group_by(sensorName, Date) %>%
   filter(n() > 12) %>%
   sample_n(12)
# A tibble: 24 x 3
# Groups:   sensorName, Date [2]
#   fullPath                      sensorName Date               
#   <chr>                         <chr>      <dttm>             
# 1 S4A00440_20180508_193000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
# 2 S4A00440_20180508_160000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
# 3 S4A00440_20180508_183000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
# 4 S4A00440_20180508_190000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
# 5 S4A00440_20180508_200000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
# 6 S4A00440_20180508_150000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
# 7 S4A00440_20180508_230000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
# 8 S4A00440_20180508_223000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
# 9 S4A00440_20180508_163000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
#10 S4A00440_20180508_133000.flac S4A00440   2018-05-08 00:00:00
# … with 14 more rows
```